# Table view scrolling / dequeueReusableCell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view & a custom cell. the cell contains 3 buttons (check box type) . on button click the respective buttons text i need to change (check / uncheck).
I achieved this, but when i click 1st button on top cell and scroll down the new cell at the bottom also has this check mark, and when i scroll back to top the check mark is moved to next cell.. how to fix this??

code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *strCellIdentifier = @"RemoteCell";


    RemoteCustomCell *cell = (RemoteCustomCell*)[tableView ![dequeueReusableCell][2]WithIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RemoteCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
    }
    else    {
        cell = [cell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCellIdentifier];
    }

  [cell.btnCheck1 addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckButton1_Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];            
    }
    return cell;

}


- (void)CheckButton1_Click:(UIButton*)sender
{
    RemoteControllCustomCell *clickedCell = (RemoteControllCustomCell *)[[sender superview] superview];

    if(clickedCell.btnCheck1.selected)
    {      
        [clickedCell.btnCheck1 setTitle:@"O" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
        clickedCell.btnCheck1.selected = NO;
    }
    else
    {      
        [clickedCell.btnCheck1 setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        clickedCell.btnCheck1.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your RemoteCustomCell.m file you should implement

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
     [super prepareForReuse];
     cell.btnCheck1.selected = NO;
}
```

This way every cell that is reused will have it's btnCheck1.selected value set to NO, and when you load your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will only set it to YES when the cell comes visible and you set it to that.

But it is key to store all your values in an NSMutableArray. There is no such thing as storing your values in the cells only, they get reused on a basis that can not be foreseen. Add your values to the array and use `[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` to open those values in a cell.

An example:

Somewhere in viewDidLoad

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"0", @"1", @"1", nil];
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
BOOL yesOrNo = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
```

And then set your button.selected to the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue, where you are relying on the UI to the job of your model. The model, the thing that you should pass to your `UITableViewCell`, so it can be built, would tell it, if it should be displaying an "X" or an "O". Since you are not doing this, the easiest solution, would be to simply reset the state of the cell everytime it gets dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the state in a array and check the state in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

CheckButton1_Click do change the state, but when dequeueReusableCell , it loads from cellForRowAtIndexPath again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have dequeue of cell issue. You may implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RemoteCell";
    RemoteCustomCell *cell = (RemoteCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        NSArray *arrNib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell= (RemoteCustomCell *)[arrNib objectAtIndex:0];   
    }
    [cell.btnCheck1 addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckButton1_Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    return cell;
}
```